# What mean & 0x40 and << 7

Tags: c#, .net

I've a list with 10 values (bytes, hex). The list is converted to decimal:

> 09 04 5A 14 4F 7D

to

> 9 4 90 20 79 125

After that. There is a method (parameter: `List<Byte> byteList`). Can anybody explain me the following code in that method:

```
"Test:" + ((((UInt16)byteList[(Int32)index] & 0x40) << 1) >> 7):
```

Especially `& 0x40` and `<< 1` and `>> 7`

Comment: `<<` and `>>` is bitwise shifting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

0x40 is hex 40 - aka 64 in decimal, or 01000000 in binary. `&` is bitwise "and", so `{expr} & 0x40` means "take just the 7th bit". `<<` is left shift, and `>>` is right shift. So this:

- takes the 7th bit
- left shifts 1
- right shifts 7
- leaving the 7th bit in the LSB position, so the final value will be either 0 (if the 7th bit wasn't set) or 1 (if the 7th bit was set)

frankly, it would be easier to just `>> 6`, or to just compare against 0. Likewise, casting to `short` (`UInt16`) is not useful here.

If I wanted to test the 7th bit, I would just have done:

```
bool isSet = (byteList[(int)index] & 0x40) != 0;
```

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for your answer. One last question. Why should I rightshift 6? With 0x40 I take the 7th bit. Do I have to bring the 7bit to the LSB to check, if it 0 or 1? Is that correct?

Comment: @Stampy well, that is what *whoever wrote the code* is doing, yes. You don't *need* to do that though - as shown by my last line.

Answer (score 2):

This is a test to verify if 7th bit of value is set. Result will be 1 if bit is set, and 0 if not.